# How do you center a section title?

Tags: sectioning

I'm using the **AMS package** in LaTeX and I added a \section{} line, but I want it to be in the center instead of aligned to the margin. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean with AMS package? Please add a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: The American Mathematical Society. Literally all I want is to center \section{title} and that's it, I'm not asking about a whole document.

Comment: That's clearly different. That is the titlesec package, this is the AMS package.

Comment: We know what AMS is, but using e.g. `amsmath` does not make any difference to sectioning. So it is *really important* to see a code example as mentioned.

Comment: @james: Do you mean `amsart` or `amsbook`?

Comment: If you are using the `amsart` or `amsbook` document *classes* then sections are centred by default. If you are simply using the `amsmath` *package*, then your document class probably doesn't centre sections by default, hence the need to use `titlesec` as well.

Comment: @james Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? This would clear up a lot of the confusion among us.